# How to use FULLTEXT search with nested include in sequelize?

Tags: mariadb, sequelize.js, full-text-search

I'm using sequelize to work with a MariaDB database and I need to do a full text search on two columns: `order.comment` and `order.orderProducts.product.name`.

I have added FULLTEXT indexes on the `order.name`, `product.name` and `user.name` columns.

Here's my code:

```
if (search) {
  where = Sequelize.literal(
    `MATCH(order.comment) AGAINST('*${search}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR
    MATCH(orderProducts.product.name) AGAINST('*${search}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR
    MATCH(user.name) AGAINST('*${search}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`,
  );
}

const orders = await this.orderModel.findAndCountAll({
  subQuery: false,
  limit,
  offset,
  distinct: true,
  order: [['id', 'DESC']],
  where,
  include: [
    {
      model: User,
    },
    {
      model: OrderProduct,
      include: [
        {
          model: Product,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});
```

When I search for something I get an error:
`Unknown column 'orderProducts.product.name' in 'where clause'`

Without `MATCH(orderProducts.product.name) AGAINST('*${search}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` everything works.

I don't understand why this is happening and how can I fix it. I tried different options but without success.

My models:

```
@Table({
  tableName: 'orders',
  indexes: [{ type: 'FULLTEXT', fields: ['comment'] }],
})
export class Order extends Model<Order> {
  @Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  })
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: DataType.TEXT, allowNull: false })
  comment: string;

  @HasMany(() => OrderProduct, { foreignKey: 'orderId' })
  orderProducts: OrderProduct[];
}
```

```
@Table({
  tableName: 'products',
  indexes: [{ type: 'FULLTEXT', fields: ['name'] }],
})
export class Product extends Model<Product> {
  @Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  })
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, unique: true, allowNull: false })
  name: string;

  @HasMany(() => OrderProduct, { foreignKey: 'productId' })
  orderProducts: OrderProduct[];
}
```

```
@Table({ tableName: 'order_products' })
export class OrderProduct extends Model<OrderProduct> {
  @Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  })
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: DataType.INTEGER, allowNull: false })
  price: number;

  @ForeignKey(() => Product)
  @Column({ type: DataType.INTEGER })
  productId: number;

  @ForeignKey(() => Order)
  @Column({ type: DataType.INTEGER })
  orderId: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => Product, { foreignKey: 'productId' })
  product: Product;

  @BelongsTo(() => Order, { foreignKey: 'orderId' })
  order: Order;
}
```

P.S.
I've tried these variations:

```
/* ----1---- */
if (search) {
  where = Sequelize.literal(
    `MATCH(product.name) AGAINST('*${search}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`,
  );
}
/* ----2---- */
if (search) {
  where = Sequelize.literal(
    `MATCH(Product.name) AGAINST('*${search}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`,
  );
}
/* ----3---- */
if (search) {
  where = Sequelize.literal(
    `MATCH(OrderProducts.Product.name) AGAINST('*${search}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`,
  );
}
```

The error is the same.

SQL query on error:

```
sql: SELECT count(DISTINCT(`Order`.`id`)) AS `count` FROM `orders` AS `Order` LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` AS `user` ON `Order`.`userId` = `user`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `order_products` AS `orderProducts` ON `Order`.`id` = `orderProducts`.`orderId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `products` AS `orderProducts->product` ON `orderProducts`.`productId` = `orderProducts->product`.`id`  WHERE MATCH(orderProducts.product.name) AGAINST('*hello*' IN BOOLEAN MODE); - parameters:[]
```

Comment: Do you have dots (`.`) in the column names?

Comment: orderProducts.product.name is the name column of the product table in the orderProducts database.  is that what you mean to search?

Comment: @RickJames No. This is equivalent to `orderProducts->product.name`

Comment: @ysth `orderProducts` is a table that has `orderId` and `productId` columns.

Comment: then your literal sql should only say `product.name`, without the `orderProducts.`.

Comment: @ysth I already tried this

Comment: @Alexei and what happened?   edit your question to show trying that and the results.   and if you reorder the matches to put user.name first, does it complain about that column being unknown?

Comment: @ysth I have added additional information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see Sequelize is joining products like this:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `products` AS `orderProducts->product`
```

giving it an alias of orderProducts->product, which contains special characters so needs to be enclosed in backticks when used. So your literal sql should use the column:

```
`orderProducts->product`.name
```

Escape the backticks to include it in your template literal:

```
`MATCH(\`orderProducts->product\`.name) AGAINST('*${search}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`,
```